# Fixed size text area

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I need to include some Java code in a Word document. It looks bad when it takes 1-2 pages. I'd like to put it in some kind of  text area with a scrollbar. Does MS Word have such a feature?

PS
This document won't be printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create file htmlarea.html:

```
<html>
 <body>
 <textarea cols="80" rows="12" wrap="virtual"></textarea>
 </body>
</html>
```

Open file in Internet Explorer. Press Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C. (copy htmltextarea)

[image: Open file in Internet Explorer]
Press Ctrl+V in Microsoft Word. (paste htmltextarea)

[image: htmltextarea in Microsoft Word 2007]

Resize htmltextarea in Design mode.

## Waring! Design mode may clear htmltextarea text in unsave document!

[image: Resize htmltextarea]

Close Design mode. Insert text. Not table or image, text only. The text is not color.
[image: Insert text]